# Apply validation rule to all strings in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a requirement to restrict special characters from all input fields in an MVC application.

This can be achieved on a per field basis using a Regular Expression DataAnnotation.

e.g. 
`[RegularExpression("^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$", ErrorMessage = "Special characters are not permitted")]
public string TestString {get; set; }`

How can this be applied to all string model properties by default in the application?

Many Thanks!

Comment: You cannot. But your simplify it to (say) `[AlphaOnly]` by inheriting from `RegularExpressionAttribute` and setting a default error message

Comment: You could use `Fody` to add attributes to your existing strings - but you'll need to write your own add-in to do it. See https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/automatic-dotnet-code-weaving-fody .

Comment: Create a custom Action Filter and write validation logic there, then register it globally. You will have to use reflection in the action filter, it should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that.

Attributes are primarily a mechanism for finding additional declarative information about a class/method/parameter at run-time by using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply validation for **each and every property** that is declared in your model class because validation expression are bound for `individual property`.